# How to click on a "pane" using UI automation library?

Tags: c#, ui-automation, microsoft-ui-automation

We have an application in which I need to click on a Pane. I tried to use the following code, which I use to click on a button, but it gave Unsupported pattern exception.

`InvokePattern click_pattern = (InvokePattern)adjust_button.GetCurrentPattern(InvokePattern.Pattern);
click_pattern.Invoke();`

Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: Is adjust_button a Pane? What control is a Pane anyway?

Comment: Its basically a pane but in application its used as a button (clickable object)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though the object is clickable, depending on how the click is being handled internally, you may not necessarily be able to use the InvokePattern to perform a click. That appears to be the case here.

As an alternative, you can use some code to move the mouse cursor over the pane and issue a click using P/Invoke. Something like this:

```
private const UInt32 MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x0002;
private const UInt32 MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x0004;

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern void mouse_event(UInt32 dwFlags, UInt32 dx, UInt32 dy, UInt32 dwData, IntPtr dwExtraInfo);

...
...

AutomationElement paneToClick;

...
...

Cursor.Position = paneToClick.GetClickablePoint();
mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, new IntPtr());
mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, new IntPtr());
```