# Can't get children of DevExpress combobox via native UI API for Windows 7

Tags: c#, wpf, testing, devexpress, ui-automation

I work at process of automating of testing GUI of one windows desktop application. In general, GUI of one was developed with WPF and DevExpress controls were used such as combobox (in fact, it's panel with edit and button inside).
So I have faced with such problem: when I has gotten panel (combobox), I can't get edit or button controls inside of panel. I use Inspect.exe to get info about UI controls and I can get and navigate to panel as well as edit and button controls inside. I know, there are a lot of information on this theme and I know that Inspect.exe uses native UI API, so I has rewritten my code using native API, but problem still rises.

Code below is how I try to retrieve controls inside of wrapped panel (combobox):

```
public void findButtondWithUnmanagedApi(AutomationElement win){
/* win - current window where I try to find my target controls.     
 * win is instance of AutomationElement (Yes, I know AutomationElement is managed code, but I use it only for getting pointer to my windows and will reduced futher)
 */

IntPtr hwnd = (IntPtr)win.Current.NativeWindowHandle;
interop.UIAutomationCore.IUIAutomation automation = new interop.UIAutomationCore.CUIAutomation();
interop.UIAutomationCore.IUIAutomationElement element = automation.ElementFromHandle(hwnd);
interop.UIAutomationCore.IUIAutomationTreeWalker walker = automation.RawViewWalker;
interop.UIAutomationCore.IUIAutomationElement child = walker.GetFirstChildElement(element);

int level = 0;

/*
 * Scaning all controlls on the form to find target panel which represents a combobox
 */
while (child != null) {

    string name = child.CurrentName;
    string aid = child.CurrentAutomationId != null ? child.CurrentAutomationId : "null";
    string type = child.CurrentLocalizedControlType;

    log.TraceInformation("child: {0}, {1}, {2}, {3}", name, type, aid, level);

    // Some controls have value of the property "Name" and don't have value of AutomationId
    if (name == "PanelControlFromTo" || name == "panelControlSystem")
    {
        level++;
        child = walker.GetFirstChildElement(child);
        continue;
    }

    /*
     * lookUpEditSystem - is value of AutomationId property of target panel (combobox from DevExpress)
     * If target panel has found then stop scanning of other element
     */
    if (child.CurrentAutomationId == "lookUpEditSystem"){
        break;
    }

    child = walker.GetNextSiblingElement(child);
}

interop.UIAutomationCore.IUIAutomationElement comboboxChild = walker.GetFirstChildElement(child);

log.TraceInformation("Combobox Child: {0}", comboboxChild  == null ? null: comboboxChild.CurrentName);
log.Flush();
}
```

In log I see the result:

```
TestLog Information: 0 : Combobox Child:
```

In Inspect.exe I see:
[Info about combobox in Inspect.exe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDR7h.png)

As you can see Inspect shows, that "lookUpEditeSystem" panel has two children. Btw, each of these children has value "IsWindowPatternAvailable" property equal to false.

I has spent 3 day trying to solve this problem and nothing.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If inspect.exe shows something, than you have access to the same information. But it's difficult to help w/o a real reproducing code. Sometimes, it's a matter of timing: you have to *wait* until item appear (because of async stuff in the controls, or whatever), instead of just searching for it.

Comment: In the code you missed comboboxChild param in last TraceInformation call.

Comment: @VasilyRyabov, thanks a lot:), but, unfortunately, this is not root cause. I've added delay in 5 sec before I start to scan form, but combobox still be hidden

Comment: Can you add an Inspect.exe screenshot for both children of the pane also?

Comment: These are the children of the lookUpEditSystem [editPane]:https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2vztf20q9OjQjVDMngwVlR1Q2c  <br/> [openBtn]: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2vztf20q9OjVlVyN0N4WDNrUmc <br/>

Comment: As work around, I expand combobox by click on panel area via simulating of left mouse button DOWN and UP events, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12662426/how-to-click-on-a-pane-using-ui-automation-library). But I hope, the proper way for accessing combobox using UI Automation methods will be find.